# Call function in a new function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a function:

```
def get_translations(string):
    """stuff"""
    list1 = []
    empty = []
    lines = string.splitlines()
    order = 1 if string.split(',')[0] == "english" else -1
    
    if 'english,māori' in string:
        for seperate_words in lines:
            list1.append(tuple(seperate_words.split(",")[::order]))
        return list1[1:]
    
    if 'māori,english' in string:
        for seperate_words in lines:
            list1.append(tuple(seperate_words.split(",")[::order]))
        return list1[1:]    
    
    else:
        print("Header language not recognized!")
        return empty
```

I am trying to call this function in a new function get_translations_from_file so I can perform what the first function is meant to do. This is because I am trying to open a file and use that file as the string for the first function. This is what I have tried to call the first function but I have had no success:

```
def get_translations_from_file(filename):
    """stuff"""
    file = open(filename)
    string = file.read()
    get_translations(string)
```

The test is:

```
filename = 'places.txt'
for terms in get_translations_from_file(filename):
    print(terms)
```

The contents of the file is:

```
english,māori
New Zealand,Aotearoa
North Island,Te Ika-a-Māui
South Island,Te Waipounamu
Wellington,Te Whanganui a Tara
Christchurch,Ōtautahi
Hamilton,Kirikiriroa
Auckland,Tāmaki Makaurau
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `get_translations`, but ignoring the return value. Since `get_translations_from_file` has no explicit `return` statement, it implicitly returns `None`. To make a long story short, you need to return the value from `get_translations`:

```
def get_translations_from_file(filename):
    """stuff"""
    file = open(filename)
    string = file.read()
    return get_translations(string) # Here!
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but now Its resulting in "Header language not recognized!" however it should be recognized. The result should be
  ('New Zealand', 'Aotearoa'),
  ('North Island', 'Te Ika-a-Māui'),... Do you have any ideas on why this is?